# Dynamic Data Web Site, how to leave out columns?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I used VS 2012 to create a Dynamic Data Web Site using the standard built in template. Using EF I have added the database to the project that I want to use, and only selected the tables I saw fit for managing data through a web site. On the first page, you get the list of tables, when you click on one of those tables, it brings up a list of everything that's in that table(rows and columns). I'm very new to doing this type of thing and I'm wondering how I can make it so only certain COLUMNS appear. I want to do this because when you click on a table, if there are more columns than a few, they drag way off the right side of the browser. So basically I just want to display only columns that I think will be relevant. BTW, this project is in ASP.NET using EF for the data model. I still want these columns to be viewable when you click on the "Details" link for the row you want to see, I just want them to not show up in the list view. How can I do this, and what files do I need to modify?

Comment: One other thing, I know about Scaffolding, only problem with that is that when i set it to true on the columns that i don't want displayed, it eliminates the ability to edit those columns in the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave out columns by using the [ScaffoldColumn(false)] data annotation attribute. I have a similar case where I do not want to include the CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, and UpdatedOn columns. See the code sample to see how to exclude them.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace S1000DDecision.Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Category
    /// </summary>
    [ScaffoldTable(true)]
    [MetadataType(typeof(CategoryMetadata))]
    public partial class Category
    {

    }

    public class CategoryMetadata
    {   
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Object CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Object CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Object UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Object UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    }
}
```